# OrCAD PCB Designer (allegro) star meaning (*) in symbols

Tags: pcb-design, footprint, allegro

Sometimes symbols include a (*) as text as part of the symbols land pattern.
Like in the following image, what is that intended for?

I have noticed that on the Package editor, the start symbol appear when you make a copy of text instead of an actual copy.

Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: To find out what it really is you must check what layer it is on.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to select "Text" in the Find filter and hover over the asterisk. It will tell you what layer this symbol exists on and will give you a pretty good idea of its intent. If I had to guess, I would suspect it is most likely the assembly drawing designator, though considering its position, perhaps it used to be a "1" indicating pin 1 on the assembly layer?